# django template language is not the same as jinja2

Tags: django, python-3.x

i'm new in Django. i'm really curious to Django template language. i have used jinja2 before Django template language. Some people says that jinja2 and Django template language are the same. But i stuck on if statement on Django template language. usually when we are comparing some value to "True" we are usually not using "==" :

```
{% if somevalue %}
.....
{% endif %}
```

instead of....

```
{% if somevalue == true %}
.....
{% endif %}
```

i can't do the first method... why ???

Comment: Jinja is indeed not the same as DTL, but in this case there is absolutely no difference in how the languages will behave with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja templates took inspiration from (copied and extended) Django templates which is why they are similar in many ways.

The first "if" block will be rendered if `somevalue` is "truthy" (not False, 0, blank string, empty collection or `object`s class has a [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method that is returning `True`) and the second "if" block will be rendered if `somevalue` is equal to `True` which would be when `somevalue` is either `True` or `1`